# Android how can you implement moveToPosition with a Custom Adapter

Tags: android, adapter

I have a simple custom adapter.  I need to set the  starting position to different positions at different times.  When using a standard listadapter, I can simply use myCursor.moveToPosition( i ).  A custom adapter using getview does not work that way.  Can anyone tell me how to move the current list to the position I want?

Comment: Try using the getCursor().moveToPosition() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ListView is available, use: `getListView().setSelection( i );`

(or  `myListView.setSelection(i);` )

You can also get the *current* position (to return to in onResume, perhaps) by using:

`int myPosition = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();`